# Ignore an element in cts:search having blank value

Tags: marklogic

I am performing cts:search using a particular document element. But when the element has no value/blank in DB, it is returning wrong result. So I want to ignore the search if the element value is blank.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `cts:element-value-query` wrapped in a `cts:not-query` for that purpose. Something like:

```
cts:not-query(
  cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("my-elem"), "")
)
```

HTH!